# Python SSL Problem with PIP, Requests and Other

Tags: python, ssl, pip, python-requests

I've got a problem with a **SSLError** that appeared since last week.
I've used Python on my machine for a few years without any problem, but now whenever i try to use a library that connects to the web, a SSLError is thrown.
I've tried other solutions to make PIP and Requests work while avoiding the certificate check, but now i need to make it work to use an Azure library.

I know it's not a problem of the Wifi connection i'm using because it works fine on other machines. Could it be something i've installed on the machine? Maybe a VPN? Is there a way to check what is "blocking" the connection?

This is an example of the error when using the Azure Iot Hub library:

```
ClientRequestError: Error occurred in request., SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='iothubstreamdemo.azure-devices.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /devices?api-version=2020-03-01 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:3622)'),))
```

And this is while using requests:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:3622)'),))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the error you get with more details to the question?

Comment: I've added the examples.